# Struggling with sprintf... something stupid?

Tags: c++, c, printf

Sorry to pester everyone, but this has been causing me some pain. Here's the code:

```
char buf[500];
sprintf(buf,"D:\\Important\\Calibration\\Results\\model_%i.xml",mEstimatingModelID);
```

mEstimatingModelID is an integer, currently holding value 0.

Simple enough, but debugging shows this is happening:

```
0x0795f630 "n\Results\model_0.xml"
```

I.e. it's missing the start of the string.

Any ideas? This is simple stuff, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's not the debugger fooling you? Try a debug build with optimizations turned off or, easier, printf the value of `buf`.

Comment: When are you examining the result: in this function, or sometime later? You're not returning a pointer to "buf" from this function, are you? You probably know this, but you can't return a pointer to a stack-based variable from a function; the variable becomes garbage as soon as the function returns.

Comment: Works standalone in Ideone - http://www.ideone.com/wJJ6o, looks like your debugger is playing up.

Comment: Thanks everyone, Alex was right, it was my debugger. I was debugging a 'release' build configuration in VC++ which wasn't showing the correct value. I was also thwarted by MATLAB not releasing file handles.... but that's another story!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

In an effort to make this an actual general answer: Here's a checklist for similar errors:

- Never trust what you see in release mode, especially local variables that have been allocated from stack memory.  Static variables that exist in heap data are about the only thing that will generally be correct but even then, don't trust it. (Which was the case for the user above)
  It's been my experience that the more recent versions of VS have less reliable release mode data (probably b/c they optimize much more in release, or maybe it's 64bitness or whatever)
- Always verify that you are examining the variable in the correct function.  It is very easy  to have a variable named "buf" in a higher function that has some uninitialized garbage in it.  This would be easily confused with the same named variable in the lower subroutine/function.
- It's always a good idea to double check for buffer overruns. If you ever use a %s in your sprintf, you *could* get a buffer overrun.
- Check your types. sprintf is pretty adaptable and you can easily get a non-crashing but strange result by passing in a string pointer when an int is expected etc.

Comment: You might also add that `snprintf()` can largely avoid buffer overflow problems, though the version provided by MS is not fully compliant with the C99 standard and does not guarantee a null-terminated string (for reasons best known to MS).

Comment: +1 for the not trusting whatever one sees in release mode in the debugger.